# List Magento customers that haven't ordered in the past 12 months

Tags: mysql, magento, filter, orders

In Magento v1.9 I need a MYSQL select that would do the following:

- list all the customers that did not place any orders in the past 12 months

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Basically you want customers that have never placed an order or customers whose last order was over 12 months ago.
You could do it using a customer collection:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P12M'));
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$customers->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('o' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
    'o.customer_id = e.entity_id',
    array(
        'last_order_date' => 'MAX(o.created_at)',
    )
);
$customers->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
    ->getSelect()
    ->having('last_order_date < ?',$date->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->orHaving('last_order_date IS NULL');
```

Or if you want the mysql for that just call
`$customers->getSelect();`

And that will give you the following MYSQL query

```
SELECT `e`.*, MAX(o.created_at) AS `last_order_date` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `o` ON o.customer_id = e.entity_id WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (last_order_date < '2014-03-26') OR (last_order_date IS NULL)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works really great, thanks! Can you also include in the MYSQL query how to add clients name, address and telephone beside the email address? I tried using:

SELECT `e`.*, MAX(o.created_at) AS `last_order_date`, 
customer_firstname, customer_lastname
 FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `o` ON o.customer_id = e.entity_id WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (last_order_date < '2014-03-26') OR (last_order_date IS NULL)

but it's not returning a name for each of the customers - only for some. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that in a MYSQL query, but if you're doing it in PHP then you could change line 3 to: `$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to use this type of code to get only customers who HAVE bought in the last 12 months